# Wordpress Plugin to set page live

Tags: wordpress

I have used Post Expirator in the past to archive (Draft) pages and posts when they reach a certain deadline. Is there a plugin available to do the opposite: set a page live once it hits a certain time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has this functionality built in. It's on the right hand side (default is 'immediately')

If you don't see it, then try upgrading to the latest version

Comment: You know I have never noticed that before. I have always published immediately. In 4+ years of using WordPress....

Comment: It's funny what we can overlook when we become servants to routine.